# Making Intellisense see resources generated by custom MSBuild target (WPF)

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, msbuild, resources, intellisense

In my net4.8 WPF project I have an `Art` folder which contains `.svg` files.

I have created an `MSBuild` target which:

1. Invokes `inkscape` to convert `.svg` files to `.xaml`, placing the generated files in the project's intermediate output directory.
2. Includes the generated `.xaml` files into the target binary as resources.

Then, in the `XAML` of my application, I have `<Frame>` elements that reference the `.xaml` resources to display the images.

So far, so good; all this works.

The problem is that when I do this, intellisense knows nothing of my generated resource files. I would like intellisense to know those files, and give me suggestions, because the application is bound to have lots of them, so using blind binding-by-name is soon going to be problematic.

Steps to reproduce the problem:

**STEP 1:** make sure you have a relatively recent version of inkscape installed and accessible via your path.

**STEP 2:** Create a new C# Windows Desktop "WPF App (.NET Framework)" application project (+solution) targeting `.Net Framework 4.8`.

**STEP 3:** Add a `XamlFromSvg.targets` file with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <!-- Ensure Visual Studio puts the XamlFromSvg item in the Build Action dropdown -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <AvailableItemName Include="XamlFromSvg"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- Instruct MsBuild to include our "Compile" and "Resource" targets in the Build -->
    <PropertyGroup>
        <BuildDependsOn>
            XamlFromSvgCompile;
            XamlFromSvgResource;
            $(BuildDependsOn);
        </BuildDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <!-- Convert ("compile") .svg to .svg.xaml -->
    <Target Name="XamlFromSvgCompile" Condition="@(XamlFromSvg)!=''" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild;BeforeRebuild"
            Inputs="@(XamlFromSvg)" 
            Outputs="$(IntermediateOutputPath)X\%(XamlFromSvg.Identity).xaml">
        <Message Importance="High" Text="XamlFromSvgCompile: %(XamlFromSvg.Identity) -> $(IntermediateOutputPath)X\%(XamlFromSvg.Identity).xaml"/>
        <MakeDir Directories="$(IntermediateOutputPath)X\%(XamlFromSvg.RelativeDir)" Condition="!Exists('$(IntermediateOutputPath)X\%(XamlFromSvg.RelativeDir)')"/>
        <Exec Command="cmd /c inkscape &quot;%(XamlFromSvg.Identity)&quot; --export-filename=&quot;$(IntermediateOutputPath)X\%(XamlFromSvg.Identity).xaml&quot;"
                Outputs="$(IntermediateOutputPath)X\%(XamlFromSvg.Identity).xaml">
        </Exec>
    </Target>

    <!-- Add .svg.xaml as resource -->
    <Target Name="XamlFromSvgResource" Condition="@(XamlFromSvg)!=''">
        <ItemGroup>
            <GeneratedXamlFromSvg Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)X\%(XamlFromSvg.Identity).xaml"/>
        </ItemGroup>
        <Message Importance="High" Text="XamlFromSvgResource: $(IntermediateOutputPath)X\@(XamlFromSvg.Identity).xaml -> %(GeneratedXamlFromSvg.Identity)"/>
        <CreateItem Include="%(GeneratedXamlFromSvg.Identity)">
            <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="Resource"/>
        </CreateItem>
    </Target>

    <!--This is here just to prevent "unknown item group" warnings. -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <XamlFromSvg Include="foo" Condition="False"/>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**STEP 4:** Near the end of `WpfApp1.csproj`, after the `<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />` line, add the following line:

```
<Import Project="XamlFromSvg.targets" />
```

**STEP 5:** Add an `/Art` folder with an `.svg` file (Say, `Misc.HamburgerMenu.svg`.) You can use the following sample `.svg` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="svg8" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <g id="g6" transform="matrix(27.777778,0,0,27.777778,-83.333334,-81.333336)">
        <path d="M 3,6 H 21 V 8 H 3 V 6 m 0,5 h 18 v 2 H 3 v -2 m 0,5 h 18 v 2 H 3 Z" id="path4" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

**STEP 6:** From within Solution Explorer, right-click on the `.svg` file and select "Include in project".

**STEP 7:** Right-click on the .svg file again, select "Properties", and set the `Build Action` to `XamlFromSvg`.

**STEP 8:** In `App.xaml` insert the following:

```
    <Frame x:Shared="false" x:Key="Icon.Misc.HamburgerMenu" Source="/X/Art/Misc.HamburgerMenu.svg.xaml" />
```

**STEP 9:** In `MainWindow.xaml`, replace `<Grid></Grid>` with the following:

```
<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource Icon.Misc.HamburgerMenu}" Margin="50"/>
```

**STEP 10:** Build and run; You should see a window displaying your `.svg` file.

**STEP 11:** Now go back to `App.xaml`. If you place the cursor on `/X/` and hit `Ctrl+Space`.

Intellisense will suggest anything but `/X/Art/Misc.HamburgerMenu.svg.xaml`. Intellisense knows nothing of this resource.

And ideas how to solve this problem or achieve the same result by other means would be welcome.

(However, any ideas aiming to achieve the same result by other means must ***actually*** achieve the same result, which is to begin with `.svg` files and to have these files displayed in a net4.8 WPF application without the need to perform any manual steps whatsoever.)

Note: I know `netcore` supports `.svg` files, but I am sticking with `net4.8` for now, which does not. And I have heard of 'XAML Islands', it seems like a clunky additional moving part held together by shoestrings, so I do not want to try it.

Also, any suggestions on how to improve `XamlFromSvg.targets` would be welcome. (I just compiled it from samples, I hardly know what I am doing.)

Comment: When I tried your steps, I got an error `obj\Debug\X\Art\Misc.HamburgerMenu.svg.xaml' cannot be found.`

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT thanks for trying. I will look into it and I will get right back to you.

Comment: In the instructions, I added the line that says `From within Solution Explorer, right-click on the `.svg` file and select "Include in project".`  However, that was probably not your problem: you had already done this, because unless you do this first, you cannot perform the next step which selects the build action.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT the only other thing that I can think of is that you do not have inkscape installed, or you do not have inkscape in your path.  Is that the case?  If installing inkscape and placing it on your path is not an option for you, then I will try to rework my question in a way that does not involve inkscape.

Comment: I have installed inkscape tool and already config its path like `C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin` into system environment. Could you please provide some content under `Misc.HamburgerMenu.svg`?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Okay, I tried to clean up my svg before posting it here, and it turns out that the whole process fails with the cleaned-up svg.  So, it appears that the process is sensitive to the content of the svg file.  I will come up with an svg file that is as small as possible and also works, and I will post it here.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT I included a sample SVG file (which works for me) in the question.  I hope you have a relatively late version of inkscape, because support for XAML files was added only recently.  I have 1.0.2.

Comment: When I enter `ctrl+space` on the cursor of `/X/`, nothing happens, did I try the wrong step? I already built it successfully and generate the xaml file. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WndR2.gif).

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT thanks for still sticking with me.  I do not know why nothing happens.  Could it be a difference in key bindings? Ctrl+Space is supposed to bring up code completion. Or could it be a difference in VS versions?  Could it be a difference introduced by resharper?  If you remove `/X`, thus using an existing path, do you get code completion?

Comment: In any case, the fact that intellisense suggests nothing to you does not change anything with regards to this question: you get no suggestions, I get irrelevant suggestions, (probably courtesy of ReSharper,) neither one of us receives the right suggestion that one would expect intellisense to give.  So, that's what this question is asking: how to get intellisense to suggest the actual path of a resource which has been auto-generated as part of the build.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT do you think I should be asking the jetbrains folks?  I am not even sure what functionality is provided by visualstudio and what functionality is provided by resharper anymore. Doesn't visualstudio intellisense provide suggestions for resources?

Comment: Sure. I think you should contact with Resharper Team. And in my side, default environment cannot get that.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Okay, thank you!